# Sync depth and color

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I am generating a depth map from the point cloud points, and to fill in the missing data I want to look at the closest matching color frame. I am able to generate a depth image (I generate it when OnDepthAvailable is called), and I see that the TangoAR unity example gets the color frames when OnExperimentalTangoImageAvailable is called.

This is from the TangoAR unity example:

```
    /// <summary>
/// This will be called when a new frame is available from the camera.
///
/// The first scan-line of the color image is reserved for metadata instead of image pixels.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cameraId">Camera identifier.</param>
public void OnExperimentalTangoImageAvailable(TangoEnums.TangoCameraId cameraId)
{
    if (cameraId == TangoEnums.TangoCameraId.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR)
    {
        m_screenUpdateTime = VideoOverlayProvider.RenderLatestFrame(TangoEnums.TangoCameraId.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);

        // Rendering the latest frame changes a bunch of OpenGL state.  Ensure Unity knows the current OpenGL state.
        GL.InvalidateState();
    }
}
```

However I want the frame right after the depth frame, not the latest frame available.

How can I sync the two as close as possible? Looking at the C RBG Depth sync example didn't help me. I understand that depth and color use the same camera, and that it can't do both at the same time (1 depth for every 4 color frames).

Comment: You could save the images in a map. And use the timestamp as key and color image as value. Then you can search for the image that has the smallest distance of time to the point cloud timestamp. And you should set the map size to maybe 20 images to remove too old images and to save memory

Comment: How did you get the SDK working in Unity3D? For me (and about 10 others I have asked) the demos always crash after about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this problem, one of them is as bashbug suggested, buffer the frames and look up texture based on closest timestamp.

What I would suggest does not require buffering, and it is Unity specific:

1. Turn on the mesh render on `PointCloud`, and set the `PointCloud` object to a specific [layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html).
2. Render `PointCloud` uses the shader suggested in [this doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DepthTextures.html), but make sure you turn the [color mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Pass.html) off, so the point cloud doesn't render to color buffer.
3. Create a `RenderTexture` and with the [depth format](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTextureFormat.Depth.html) (as the [previous doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DepthTextures.html) suggested)
4. Create a camera with the same intrinsic (projection matrix) as the `TangoARCamera`, and only render the `PointCloud`'s layer. This camera will be our depth camera (camera only renders `PointCloud`).
5. Set the depth camera as a child object of the `TangoARCamera` object with no offset. This makes sure the camera has the exact same motion (position and orientation) as ARCamera.
6. Create another render texture with RGBA format, and assign this texture to the `TangoARCamera` to get the color image.
7. Now you have two textures: depth and color. They are guaranteed to be sync'ed, because in UnitySDK, the PointCloud prefab actually project point in the world space, and TangoARCamera`'s transform is updated based on color camera timestamp.